# What is the default norm type used by cvNorm()?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I know the default value for norm_type used when calling the function is 4, but what does this correspond to? The options are NORM_INF, NORM_L1 and NORM_L2. Which of these is 4? And while I'm at it, what are the values for the rest of them? I can't find #defines for these anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are defined in `modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp`, as an `enum`:

```
enum { NORM_INF=1, NORM_L1=2, NORM_L2=4, NORM_TYPE_MASK=7, NORM_RELATIVE=8, NORM_MINMAX=32};
```

So default is L2 norm (euclidean).

Also, the [OpenCV docs](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?#norm) say that the default is `NORM_L2`.

Comment: Any link, which explains difference btw all these NormTypes??